# Running php from user onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not sure how well i'll be able to explain this, but here goes. 
I have a website for attractions. Let's say that one of my categories is Historical villages. 
When the user opens the Historical villages page he gets a list of villages displayed from the database. The way I display them is: Name plus a picture of the attraction. 
What I want to do is unable the user to click on of the villages (by making the name and picture a clickable link) and the user to be redirected to a page that will run a php script that will display more information from the database about the selected village. That way I will only have one page for all attractions that will display different information every time a user selects something different, instead of hardcoding all the pages.

This is my code displaying the lits of villages:

```
$sql = "SELECT `Name`, `Location`, `Description`, `Airport`, `imglink`, `pagelink` "
        . "FROM `attractions` "
        . "WHERE `Category`='HistV'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $row['Name'];
    echo "<img src='" . $row['imglink'] . "'>";
}
```

Do any of you have any suggestions on how to make this output a link and the make it run the PHP to show the users selection?

Comment: [google doesn't bite if you search on it](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ajax&oq=ajax&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j69i60l2j0l2.1047j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=94&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: You've said you want "a user to be redirected to a page" and then you say that you only have "one page". Do you mean have 1 page displaying all the villages, and then when they click on a village it sends them to another page which has all the attractions in that village?

Comment: @JohnConde — No need for Ajax. This only needs a link (possibly with a query string in the URL)

Comment: robobobobo Yes, exactly what I want!

Comment: ok well then as @JohnConde said there is no need for Ajax here, it's much simpler, you just need a page which will accept a parameter passed in from a query string. So your url would be something like `/attractions.php?village=SmallVille` this http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php should help

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not good with php, and I still don't understand that suggestion, how do I make it so that i give that parameter from a string?

Comment: Ok so I see how to get the parameter, but how do I use it on the next page?

Answer (score 1):

Your while condition changed to like this,

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    /* For example , 
       $row['pagelink'] must contains the pagelink as belowed here
            /viewVillage.php?village_id=1
            /viewVillage.php?village_id=2 and so on.  */
     echo "<a href='" . $row['pagelink'] . "'>"
             .  $row['Name']  .
             . "<img src='" . $row['imglink'] . "'>
           </a>";
}
```

This will generate your list of villages like this,

```
<a href="/viewVillage.php?village_id=1">
   Village name 1
   Village Image 1
</a>

<a href="/viewVillage.php?village_id=2">
   Village name 2
   Village Image 2
</a>

<a href="/viewVillage.php?village_id=3">
   Village name 3
   Village Image 3
</a>

 .....
```

When you click on any of the link, it will redirected to `viewVillage.php` page. Now you can get the particular village using `$_GET['village_id']`

**viewVillage.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['village_id']]) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ) {

    $villageId = $_GET['village_id'];
    // Then do your stuff over here
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I make it so that when the user clicks on that the next page will run a php scrip that will know what the user clicked on and will display info abou the user selection?

Comment: For that, you need to send `village_id` using `GET` method on `view page`. Now I edited my answer with comment

Answer (score 0):

On your current page

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
/* For example , 
   $row['pagelink'] should be a village id */
 echo "<a href='/attractions.php?village=" . $row['pagelink'] . "'>"
         .  $row['Name']  .
         . "<img src='" . $row['imglink'] . "'>
       </a>";
```

}

Now it would print something like

```
<a href="/attractions.php?vilage=2"> Vilage Name <img src="urltoimage"></a>
```

When you click on this link you will be sent to a file called "attractions.php"

Create this file in the same directory and it should have the following php in it

```
<?php 
$villageId = $_GET['village']; //this gets the id of the village from the url and stores
//it in a variable
//now that you have the id of the village, perform your sql lookup here
//of course you will have to fill this is, as I don't know your actual table fields and names
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Attractions WHERE villageID = `$villageID`";

 //now perform the query, loop through and print out your results
?>
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: robobobobo and Ranjith thank you guys so much for the help, it works perfectly!!!!